# Winsock: Windows networking programming in C++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I need books that truely explian sockets in windows in C++ ive been looking at tutorials but they dont tell what anything means they dont go into great detail so i need come books on Winsock in C++ for windows

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562702/best-current-book-on-windows-networking-tcp-ip-sockets-packet-filtering-firew

Comment: Duplicate from the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583940/is-there-a-beginners-book-for-c-socket-programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by far the best, most up to date book on the subject: [Network Programming for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615799). One of the nice things about this book is that is shows the range of styles from blocking sockets to completion ports.

Answer (score 1):

This textbook is a little bit outdated and it's not Windows specific, however it does cover sockets indepth: [Unix Network Programming, Volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013490012X). Winsock is Microsoft's take on Berkeley Sockets, so most of the functions in the textbook will work in Winsock as well.

Hope this helps :).